# Setting up ODBC Connection with Access database using MapBasic

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I'm trying to setup an ODBC connection in my Access database through mapbasic code, but i don't how should i start this code.

I could make it manually and able to have a link between my tables to work on.

I would like to create a tools that will open and link my tables in access and update it time to time when every time i change something on my mapinfo table.

Comment: Do you have a ODBC Data Source or are you trying to avoid creating a Data Source?

Comment: Thanks Peter. I already created an ODBC data source manually. But i don't know if i have to code it in mapbasic to call my table in access and able to have a link between tables and have it update it. I just read some forum that i have to use the code "server_connect" to be able to connect to my access db. But i don't know how should i start coding and update my table in access using mapbasic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with any database from MapInfo Pro thru MapBasic you need to first establish a connection to the database. This require a data soruce which I can understand you already have.

To open the connection you have to use the Server_Connect() function:

```
sConnString = "DSN=GIS_DB" 
'**and potentially also a username and password
sConnString = sConnString & "UID=USERNAME;PWD=SecretCode"
nConnection = Server_Connect("ODBC", sConnString)
```

Now the integer variable nConnection holds the ID of the connection that you just opened to your database.

It's now time to start using this connection. MapBasic has a number of functions and statements that can be used to work with (spatial) databases:

- Server Create Map
- Server Create Style
- Server Create Table
- Server Link Table
- Register Table
- Server Refresh
- Server Set Map
- Server_Execute
- Commit Table

If you want to create a linked table, have a look at Server Link Table statement. If you want to create a live table use the Register Table statement.

```
Server Link Table Statement:

sCmd    = "Select * From " & sSchema & "." sTable
sTab    = PathToTableName$(sFile)

Server nConnection Link Table
    sCmd
    Toolkit "ODBC"
    Into sTab
    File sFile
```

Register Table Statement:

```
sCmd    = "Select * From " & sSchema & "." sTable
sTab    = PathToTableName$(sFile)

Register Table sTab
    Type ODBC
    Connection Handle nConnection
    Toolkit "ODBC"
    Cache OFF  '**Or ON
    Table sCmd
    Into sFile

Open Table sFile
```

For MS Access you probably can leave out the Schema and just use:

```
sCmd    = "Select * From " & sTable
```

Once you got your tables open, you save the changes back to the database via the Commit Table Statement.

To Refresh a table you use the Server Refresh statement. I would recommend always running a Refresh statement after committing changes.

Comment: Thanks Peter, this was well explained. May i know if i have 3 tables to access do i have to create 3 ODBC connection?

Comment: No, you can reuse the connection for as many tables as you want - well, there is a limit somewhere but you can open a lot of tables via one connection